# How to check Natural Language Sentence Structure validity using parser in java?

Tags: parsing, nlp

I am working on a project in which there is a part where I will have to input a sentence to check whether it is a valid sentence or not.

For example, if I give the input as "I am working at home", then the output will give me "Valid Sentence" where if I give the input as "I working home am at", it will give me "Invalid Sentence".

I searched some natural language parsing methods like NLP, Stanford Parser, but it would be  helpful if someone please guide me through some java examples about the related problems.

I will be grateful in advance for this help. Thank you.

Comment: Nothing with parsing, but how about n-gram language models (see for example the Wikipedia article about "Language Models")? I strongly assume you will get more satisfying results than by employing a parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you use parse trees or not, you will need to use a [Markov process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_model) to check validity. The features can be word sequences, part-of-speech tag sequences, parse tree segments (i.e. production rules and their extensions), etc. For these, you would use a [tokenizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization), a [POS tagger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) and a [natural language parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computational_methods), respectively.

The validity check will also be a probabilistic score, not an absolute truth. All (or almost all) natural language parsers are statistical. Which means they require training data. These parsers use [context-free grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCFG) or [mildly context-sensitive grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mildly_context-sensitive_language) such as CCG or TAG, which are among the best computational approximations of natural language grammars.

Essentially, the model will tell you *how likely is it for a feature to appear in a valid sentence after a certain sequence of features has already been seen*. That is, it will allow you to compute probabilities of the form `P("at"|"am working")` and `P("at"|"home am")`. The former should have a higher probability than the latter. You will need to experimentally determine how high a probability should be in order for a sentence to be considered as valid.

As [qqlihq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388827/qqilihq) commented, these are under the broad definition of [language models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model). For sentence validity, however, you will usually not need to measure perplexity. The conditional probability measures should suffice.